# Shopware6 Loading options from twig template to Js plugin

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

I have been following https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-custom-javascript to create a javascript plugin. But, I am struggling with adding options through twig template. I have something like the following:

Twig file : product.html.twig:

```
{% set contentModalOptions = {
            cmsContentId: "some-hash",
            navigationUrl: path('frontend.cms.page'),
            failSafeRedirectUrl: '/some-failsafe-url/'
        } %}

        <div>
            <a target="_self" href="#" data-content-modal="true" data-content-modal-options="{{ contentModalOptions|json_encode|escape('html_attr') }}">
                help text
            </a>
        </div>
```

plugin file : custom-plugin.js:

```
import Plugin from 'src/plugin-system/plugin.class';

export default class ContentModalPlugin extends Plugin {

    static options = {
        cmsContentId: '',
        navigationUrl: '',
        failSafeRedirectUrl: ''
    };

    init() {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.options); // empty values
    }
}
```

Notes:

- In the browser, I see that values set using twig as the HTML attribute.
- Plugin has been registered and works with the template.

`console.log()` in the plugin doesn't print any values that are set from twig. It just shows the `options` object that has been initialized in the plugin.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show how the js plugin is registered to the plugin manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, I see what the problem was. When I registered my plugin, I had the following:

```
PluginManager.register('ContentModalPlugin', ContentModalPlugin, '[data-content-modal]');
```

So, I tried passing the options with `data-content-modal-options` attribute through twig but it seems that the resolved plugin name in `_mergeOptions()` at `src/plugin-system/plugin.class` takes the plugin name (i.e the string that is the first argument of the register function) and not the attribute definition in the register method.

So, adding a html attribute as `data-content-modal-plugin-options` based on my class name resolved the problem.

Comment: The explanation isn't quite correct. It doesn't take the class name and converts it to kebab case but the plugin name, the string that is the first argument of the `register` function. If that had been `'ContentModal'` it would've worked without changing the attributes and also been more in line how Shopware's default plugins are registered: `PluginManager.register('AddressEditor', AddressEditorPlugin, '[data-address-editor]');`

Answer (score 2):

I assume you register the plugin like this:

```js
PluginManager.register('ContentModal', ContentModalPlugin, '[data-content-modal]');
```

Within the constructor of the `Plugin` class `this.options = this._mergeOptions(options);` should then called, which in turn parses the `data-${dashedPluginName}-options` attribute. It should throw an error if it can't parse the json:

```js
`The data attribute "data-${dashedPluginName}-options" could not be parsed to json: ${e.message}`
```

Are the any errors when you look at the console of your browsers dev tools?

For further debugging you could also try calling `super._mergeOptions(this.options);` from your `init` method.

Comment: Yes, I have registered the plugin with similar what you wrote. There are no errors anywhere. Also, if I try to log `options` from the parent's constructor, I don't see any values but just `{}`. So, even if I do a `super._mergeOptions(this.options);` it will try to merge an empty options object.

So, I am wondering if the options are not passed to the plugin at all from the template. Is that a possibility?

Comment: ```
import ContentModalPlugin from './plugin/content-modal/content-modal.plugin';
...
PluginManager.register('ContentModalPlugin', ContentModalPlugin, '[data-content-modal]');
```

Comment: That's the mistake. Your plugin name mustn't end with `Plugin`: `PluginManager.register('ContentModal', ContentModalPlugin, '[data-content-modal]');` - That should work. The reason is the plugin name is used to build the attribute accessor and the attribute doesn't contain the term `plugin`: `const dashedPluginName = StringHelper.toDashCase(this._pluginName); const dataAttributeOptions = DomAccess.getAttribute(this.el, \`data-${dashedPluginName}-options\`, false);`

Comment: yeah, that seems to be the problem. Thanks for helping